# How can I automate creating a sequence from a set of clips?

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, automation, mini-dv, extendscript

I have a large amount of DV footage, which I want to convert into a video per day.

I've tried doing this by scripting `ffmpeg`:

```bash
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i day1-files.txt -fflags +igndts -ac 2 -ar 32000 -vf scale=768x576,setsar=1:1,yadif sq08_output.mov
```

but results varied from perfect to garbled audio or video.

Then I tried this manually in Premiere Pro with the following steps:

1. Import footage of a single day
2. Automate to sequence
3. Export media

Results were perfect (for the same clips that `ffmpeg` couldn't decode).

As I have thousands of clips I don't want to repeat the Premiere Pro steps manually, so I looked into [Premiere Pro scripting](https://premiere-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/)

I completed step 1 with [`app.project.importFiles`](https://premiere-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/general/project.html#project-importfiles):

```js
app.project.importFiles(["day1-1.mov", "day1-2.mov", "day1-3.mov"], true, app.project.rootItem, false)
```

I tried to do step 2 with [`app.project.createNewSequenceFromClips`](https://premiere-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/general/project.html#project-createnewsequencefromclips):

```js
app.project.createNewSequenceFromClips("sequenceName"
    , [app.project.rootItem.children[0]
    , app.project.rootItem.children[1]
    , app.project.rootItem.children[2]]
    , app.project.rootItem);
```

But got greeted with:

```
createNewSequenceFromClips is not a function
```

How can I automate creating a sequence from a set of clips?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `createNewSequenceFromClips` was not available in my version of Premiere Pro (v14.0.1). When I updated to v14.4 all worked as it should.

This [example script](https://gitlab.com/b_a/premiere-pro-automation) using that function works as expected.